# Parallax floating image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, image-gallery

I need to create parallax floating gallery - when I scroll the page, images move relative to each other and the parent container, from bottom to top of the page visible area. Here's an [example](http://www.footcardigan.com/) on another site (section - sockstagram). Basically, I need to create exactly the same effect. I've already tried to do this using the same library the mentioned example uses - Skrollr. However, it's buggy - causes issues in Safari desktop and mobile (breaks layout of some other elements on the page).  Can someone point me in right direction? jQuery plugin or some custom code to achieve this. Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parallax.js](https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax) or even a framework like [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/parallax.html) which has one implemented and adds also the benefits of having a grid-based framework to design your web.